# Autotest - Load Error - Error posted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autotest

```
bundle exec /Users/new2/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby -S /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/bin/rspec     --autotest '/Users/new2/work/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb'
/Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `require': no such file to load -- b (LoadError)
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `block in requires='
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `map'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:162:in `requires='
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:22:in `block in configure'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `each'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:17:in `run'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
        from /Users/new2/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails3tut/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
^CInterrupt a second time to quit
^C[sample_app (master)]$
```

That's the error above, been looking around. My autotest file looks good. All gems are installed. Checked to see if I could find the problem elsewhere, but wasn't successful. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I had this same error. I initially assumed it was a typo (within my project or even haphazardly made within gem source) - but even reinstalling everything to a fresh rvm gemset didn't fix anything. Turns out the problem was in my .rspec file:

WRONG:

```
-drb
```

RIGHT:

```
--drb
```

The double dash is VERY necessary ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unless the snippet was edited to remove the real missing library (which would be counter-productive) you have a typo somewhere in your app, most likely in your Gemfile.  Do you have a line similar to:

```
gem 'b'
```

Anywhere in there?  If so, something might have been truncated accidentally if you were copy/pasting from the example code.

Answer (score 0):

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', '1.2.5', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
 gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
  gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
end
```

Thats my Gemfile.

Comment: I also tried running just 'autotest' in another demo app dir. It just results in a blank terminal. I only get this error on in my 'sample_app' dir. Growl is invoked but it says "SAMPLE_APP: Could not run tests"